# How put a matrix in a row (with or without index titles) using mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am trying to put a 16x16 complex matrix in a row, with separated columns to real and imaginary parts (i.e a 1x512 matrix). Additionally this 16x16 matrix is generated by an operator `ρ[t]` and i need to put this like a matrix such that each row is an 1x512 vector.

I try with the following code.

```
data = Reap[For[t = 0, t <= Tmax , t = t + 1/10 Tmax, Sow[g0]; Sow[t]; 
 Sow[For[i = 1; j = 1, i <= 16; j <= 16, i = i + 1; j = j + 1, 
   Re[Extract[ρ[t], {i, j}]]]];
 Sow[For[k = 1; l = 1, k <= 16; l <= 16, k = k + 1; l = l + 1, 
   Im[Extract[ρ[t], {k, l}]]]]  ;    ]][[2, 1]]~Partition~34
```

What's wrong? Some trick that can I would use?

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: `Flatten[Re@ρ[#]]&/@Range[0, Tmax, Tmax/10]` and `Flatten[Im@ρ[#]]&/@Range[0, Tmax, Tmax/10]`?

Comment: Thanks, this trick works. I need to study more about the use of the simbols &, / and @.  Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ρ[t_] := t RandomComplex[1 + I, {16, 16}];
TmaX = 1;

m1 = Flatten[Re@ρ[#]] & /@ Range[0, Tmax, Tmax/10] ;
m2 = Flatten[Im@ρ[#]] & /@ Range[0, Tmax, Tmax/10];
Dimensions/@ {m1, m2}
```

> {  {11, 256}, {11, 256}}

Comment: Thanks this works, i need to study more about the use of the simbols &/@.

Comment: @SantiagoMarínAgudelo, you are welcome. Thank you for the accept and welcome mma.se. Re `&` and `/@` see [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) in the documentation center.